# Manually edit terminal command history

Tags: 12.10, gnome-terminal

My terminal history has hundreds of command, but I just want to keep a few of them

Is there a way to manually edit the list of command executed in the terminal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

While this would be rather tedious now that almost every command gets logged in your history, you can edit your `~/.bash_history` file.

Answer (score 3):

to review your history, open the terminal and just type `history`

I would recommend making a copy first by opening a terminal and using this CLI `cp ~/.bash_history ~/.bash_history_old`

then edit the "old" one, Once you are satisfied with the result run this `cp ~/.bash_history_old ~/.bash_history` this will replace the current history. You will be prompted to overwrite y/n?